# How to configure tsconfig.json to support string literals or string templates

Tags: typescript, string-literals, tsconfig

I've used swagger codgen with typescript-aurelia template to generate API code.  The result code makes a lot of usage of string literals.  The cmd-line transpolar, tsc, will throw errors about this code, but it will output javascript, which runs without error.

However, I'm using gulp-typescript in larger build tasks and it will not output javascript files when it encounters `error TS2304: Cannot find name '$'.` on code like this:

```
const url = `${this.basePath}/api/v2/courses/{courseId}`
      .replace(`{${'courseId'}}`, encodeURIComponent(String(${params['courseId']})));
```

I believe it's perfectly valid TypeScript; however, there may be a compiler option to support string literals / templates.  I just haven't found it yet.

Does anyone know how to suppress or eliminate these errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the problem is with TypeScript not supporting string literals / templates.

Instead, it looks like you are missing backticks around your final template.

You are writing:

```
encodeURIComponent(String(${params['courseId']}))
```

when it should probably be:

```
encodeURIComponent(String(`${params['courseId']}`))
```

or simply

```
encodeURIComponent(String(params['courseId']))
```